# Apple LLVM Compiler Error 4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, llvm

So, I happened to move some folders, and all of sudden my project figured it would be cool to just like, not work. Can someone please tell me how to fix this error? (Error while compiling for irl iphone.)

Short error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/OscarApeland/Downloads/LNG Converter 2/LNG Converter/LNG Converter/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Full error:

```
ProcessPCH "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/LNG Converter-Prefix-chblhzzekvnqprcbihkzfysqbmqa/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch.pth" "LNG Converter/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch" normal armv7s objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/OscarApeland/Downloads/LNG Converter 2/LNG Converter"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch armv7s -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -iquote "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/LNG-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/LNG-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/LNG-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/LNG-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include "-I/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/DerivedSources/armv7s" "-I/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/LNG Converter.build/Debug-iphoneos/LNG Converter.build/DerivedSources" -F/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos --serialize-diagnostics "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/LNG Converter-Prefix-chblhzzekvnqprcbihkzfysqbmqa/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch.dia" -c "/Users/OscarApeland/Downloads/LNG Converter 2/LNG Converter/LNG Converter/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch" -o "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/LNG Converter-Prefix-chblhzzekvnqprcbihkzfysqbmqa/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch.pth" -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Users/OscarApeland/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LNG_Converter-fhuumyzhzihyzkcrahggbbgzeijr/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/LNG Converter-Prefix-chblhzzekvnqprcbihkzfysqbmqa/LNG Converter-Prefix.pch.d"
```

And a screenshot
[image]

Comment: +1 I just restructured my files in project's folder and was facing same error. resolved now.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit the build settings for your target and update the "Prefix Header" to fix its path.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks it worked, I just restructured my files in project's folder and was facing same error.

Comment: What does it need to be updated to? I have Project/Project-Prefix.pch but I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

I had that error:  missing MyProject-Prefix.pch and also missing CordovaLib_Prefix.pch
And sure enough, I could verify that they were not where they should be.

Here is what I think happened:

- I copied all the files for my project from one directory to another (fact)
- Finder, in its wisdom, decided to not copy files ending w .pch

The reason that makes sense, is that to solve this all I had to do was copy the files from their original location to the dir where they should be.