# An error occur when using a mkmapview control clang:error: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

Actually I am using `MKMapView` control but its not working. When I run my application, I get kind of error which is mentioned below. In my application,PCH file name is: MAPVIEW-Prefix.pch.

I also referred this link: [Apple LLVM Compiler Error 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561682/apple-llvm-compiler-error-4-1)  but it didn't help me.

Error Log shows the following:

```
clang:error: no such file or directory:'set'Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Link Mapkit.Faramework with your target

Comment: I can't understand what you saying.

Comment: have you added Mapkit.Faramework to link binary with libraries in your target